# Limit the number of rows collected by IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Using `IMPORTXML` to **scrape** data from a site, it returns 5,000 rows of data. But my need is only the first 200 values. How do I limit import for this amount of rows?

I tried to do it as follows:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML("XXXXX","XXXXX"),"LIMIT 200")
```

But the first line joined the data from the first four lines. Like This:

```
Original     Expected     Result
     
A            A            ABCD
B            B            E
C            C            F
D            D            G
E            E            H
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
```

I need them all apart, each line below the other, nothing can join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either use:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML("ID", "XPath"), "limit 200", 0)
```

or:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML("ID", "XPath"), 200, 1)
```